# Initialize char**

Tags: c++, string

I'm very new to C++. I'm trying to call a function that takes in char**:

```
bool func(char** a) {
    //blablabla
}
```

So it takes in an array of c-strings. I need to create a char**, but nothing works.

```
char** a = char[255][255]; // error: type name is not allowed

char** a = new char[255][255]; // error: a value of type "char (*)[255]" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "char **"

char a[][] = {"banana", "apple"};
char** b = &a; // error: a value of type "<error-type> (*)[2]" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "char **"
```

At the end I need to do:

```
char* a[] = {"banana", "apple"};
```

Why the first few didn't work and why the last one worked?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first few didn't work for exactly the reasons the compiler gave you in the errors. Not sure what kind of other answer you expect here. Code like `char **a = char[255][255]` is simply not valid C++, so it won't compile.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a lot wrong in your code.

```
char** a = char[255][255]; // error: type name is not allowed
```

First of all this is not even valid C++ (or C for that matter). Maybe you meant:

```
char a[255][255];
```

In any case always remember that the type of a bi-dimensional dynamically allocated array is not `**` but `(*)[N]` which is very different.

```
char** a = new char[255][255]; // error: a value of type "char (*)[255]" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "char **"
```

The error message you provide in the comment explains exactly what I said earlier.

```
char a[][] = {"banana", "apple"};
```

In the above code the correct type of the variable `a` should be `char* a[]`. Again, arrays and pointer (for what the type is concerned) are very different things. A `char` array may decay to pointer (if `NULL` terminated), but for the rest, except with explicit casts, you can't use pointers and arrays like you are doing.

The last one worked because, like I said earlier, `char* []` is the correct type for an array of C-strings.

Anyway, if you just doing homework, it is ok to learn this things. But in future development using C++: try not to use "features" that start with `C-`, like C-strings, C-arrays, etc. C++'s standard library gives you `std::string`, `std::array`, `std::vector` and such *for free*.

If you *really* need to allocate dynamic memory (with `new` and `delete`, or `new[]` and `delete[]`) please use *smart pointers*, like `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 7):

You say you are working in C++. Then you can easily ignore `const char*` and `char**` and focus about what you can use:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> arrayOfStrings;
arrayOfStrings.push_back("foo");

bool func(const std::vector<std::string>>& a) {
  ..
}
```

If you know the size at compile time you can even use `std::array`:

```
std::array<255, std::string> fixedArrayOfStrings
```

EDIT: since you need to build an array of C strings in any case you can easily do it starting from the vector:

```
const char **arrayOfCstrings = new const char*[vector.size()];

for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); ++i)
  arrayOfCstrings[i] = vector[i].c_str();

func(arrayOfCstrings);

delete [] arrayOfCstrings;
```

Comment: But the function is fixed and not written by me. It's declared as "bool func(char** a)". I can't change that.

Comment: This won't compile: 1. std::vector<std::string>> (ends with an extra '>') 2. bool func(const <std::vector<std::string>>& a) the extra '<>' around std::vector is also not correct.

Comment: @TehSuu: just a typo because I was writing std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>. Don't ask me why, I still have to completely wake up ;)

Comment: @Jack hehe, happens to us all :))

Comment: I'm curious as to why you went back to using raw `new` after just introducting `std::vector`. Why not `std::vector<char const*>`?

Answer (score 2):

```
char**
```

is ambiguous - it can mean:

1. **pointer to pointer**
2. array of c-strings - experienced programmer would write `char* arr[]` instead

In the first case it is quite simple:

```
char* niceString = GetNiceString();
func(&niceString);
```

however in the second case it is slightly more complex. The function will not know the length of the array so you need to end it explicitly with a `NULL`, just like for example `environ` is:

```
char* a[3] = { "One", "Two", NULL }; /* note that this is possibly  dangerous
because you assign const char* (READ-ONLY) to char* (WRITABLE) */
func(a); // char*[] gets downgraded to char** implicitly
```

Answer (score 0):

so `char** a = char[255][255];` it's weird to C and C++
and if you want a static 2d array just

```
char a[255][255];
```

Comment: `char[255][255]` is not convertible to `char**` (since it's contiguous memory of 255 * 255 chars). It should be `char *a[255];` (255 pointers to c-strings somewhere, which can be converted to pointer to first c-string, i.e. `char**`).

Answer (score 0):

char ** is a scalar type, you have to cast to (char *[]), try this :

```
char **temp = (char *[]){"abc", "def","fg"};
```

Comment: A nice trick for C, but wouldn't work in C++.